# MathJax automatic font resizing

Tags: html, css, fonts, mathjax, autoresize

All my formulas look really nice when browser viewport is wide.

[image]

My site (Wordpress, modified Twenty Fifteen theme) has a flexible design so it is resizing images and text automatically.

[image]

However, formulas do not resize at all and it causes some problems with layout.

[image]

How to force formulas to automatically resize when the size of browser window is changing?

Comment: Use viewport units `vw` (for width in this case) as font size

Comment: Can you give us some link, where we can test this situation?

Comment: @SauravRastogi I can give a link to a site http://topmath.ru/глава-1-введение/.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) Editor to render the equation part. You cannot wrap the MathJax equations to the next line just like other HTML elements.

They have introduced another way of doing it and they call it **[Responsive Equations](https://www.mathjax.org/responsive-equations/)**. Have a look at the examples, they have shown several ways to make the equations responsive on every screen size.

You can also refer to this [**`Codepen`**](http://codepen.io/pkra/pen/jEodYw) *(this shows how to dynamically control responsiveness of equations)*

Responsive Equations: https://www.mathjax.org/responsive-equations/

Hope this helps!

Comment: MathJax can automatically linebreak, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html#automatic-line-breaking